# Failed to execute goal net.alchim31.maven:scala-maven-plugin:4.3.1:compile (default-sbt-compile)

Tags: java, scala, maven, apache-spark, intellij-idea

**Issue while building Maven project with `mvn install` - Scala Compilation Error**

I am encountering an error while trying to build my Maven project using the `mvn install` command. The error message is as follows:

```xml
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal net.alchim31.maven:scala-maven-plugin:4.3.1:compile (default-sbt-compile) on project spark-commons: Execution default-sbt-compile of goal net.alchim31.maven:scala-maven-plugin:4.3.1:compile failed.: CompileFailed -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal net.alchim31.maven:scala-maven-plugin:4.3.1:compile (default-sbt-compile) on project spark-commons: Execution default-sbt-compile of goal net.alchim31.maven:scala-maven-plugin:4.3.1:compile failed.
```

command **mvn -X** gives the following :

```xml
Apache Maven 3.9.6 (bc0240f3c744dd6b6ec2920b3cd08dcc295161ae)
Maven home: C:\Program Files\maven\apache-maven-3.9.6
Java version: 11.0.22, vendor: Eclipse Adoptium, runtime: C:\Users\PRBW9435\AppData\Local\Coursier\cache\arc\https\github.com\adoptium\temurin11-binaries\releases\download\jdk-11.0.22%252B7\OpenJDK11U-jdk_x64_windows_hotspot_11.0.22_7.zip\jdk-11.0.22+7
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 11", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"


[ERROR] No goals have been specified for this build. You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>. Available lifecycle phases are: pre-clean, clean, post-clean, validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy. -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.NoGoalSpecifiedException: No goals have been specified for this build. You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>. Available lifecycle phases are: pre-clean, clean, post-clean, validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy.
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:91)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:261)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:173)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:906)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:283)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:206)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:283)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:226)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:407)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:348)
[ERROR]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following
```

Here is my `pom.xml`:

```xml
<properties>
        <modules-spark.version>3.18.2</modules-spark.version>
        <testng.version>7.4.0</testng.version>
        <surefire-testng.version>3.0.0-M5</surefire-testng.version>
        <jacoco-maven-plugin.version>0.8.6</jacoco-maven-plugin.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.obs.utils</groupId>
                <artifactId>stream-spark_${scala.version.major}</artifactId>
                <version>${modules-spark.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.typesafe.play/play-json -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.typesafe.play</groupId>
                <artifactId>play-json_2.11</artifactId>
                <version>2.7.4</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>  <!-- declare the exclusion here -->
                        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
                <version>2.10.0</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- functional testing -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
                <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
                <version>${testng.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-jar-plugin -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
            </dependency>

        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.obs.utils</groupId>
            <artifactId>stream-spark_${scala.version.major}</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.typesafe.play/play-json -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.typesafe.play</groupId>
            <artifactId>play-json_2.11</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- functional testing -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>releases</id>
            <uniqueVersion>true</uniqueVersion>
            <url>https://repos.tech.orange/artifactory/socle-edh-virt-maven-stable</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
    </distributionManagement>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0-M1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <skip>true</skip>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${jacoco-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                    <executions>
                        <!-- to avoid bugs in some situations -->
                        <execution>
                            <id>default-prepare-agent</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>

                        <!-- create report during maven verify phase -->
                        <execution>
                            <id>report</id>
                            <phase>verify</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>report</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**Project Configuration Details:**

- **JDK Version:** 1.8

I have also configured the `maven-jar-plugin` version 3.2.0 and `jacoco-maven-plugin` version 0.8.6 for reporting.

**Build Configuration:**
I have configured the `jacoco-maven-plugin` for code coverage reporting during the `verify` phase.

**Request for Help:**
If anyone has experience with this issue or can provide assistance in resolving the Scala compilation error, I would greatly appreciate it. Please note that I am using JDK 1.8.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried to run `mvn` with the `-e` option (first) and `-X` (if `-e` doesn't work) to see the full error message?

Comment: From the message I would guess it is a Scala compilation error.I am surprised that the plugin does not show the error! Are you sure your Scala code compiles (how are you checking)? The plugin seems to have a command that runs the compiler continuously (`mvn scala:cc`) maybe this provides more meaningful messages? And/or try the `-X` switch too.

Comment: If you want help then follow @NikosParaskevopoulos suggestions. We can not help if you don't provide enough details.

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos  I've run the mvn -X command you can see the result

Comment: I don't know why it showed jdk 11 , while I m using jdk 1.8  (mvn -X)

Comment: Try running mvn **with** the `-e` / `-X` switches, i.e. the command you would normally run is `mvn package` try `mvn -X package`. The output from `mvn -X`, as included in the question, is of no use!

Comment: Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginContainerException: An API incompatibility was encountered while executing net.alchim31.maven:scala-maven-plugin:4.3.1:compile: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError @NikosParaskevopoulos

Comment: Could it be that the plugin is not compatible with your Maven version? Which is the method it cannot find? I suggest you add the full stack trace to the question!

Comment: Well its fixed I've changed maven version to 3.8.1 with jdk 1.8 and its working for me